# Adding underscore and jpg to the output field

Tags: reporting-services

The output from my Parameter is FirstName LastName.

I want the final to be FirstName_LastName.jpg.  Below is what I would do in SQL but how can I do the same in my SSRS report?

update @signatures set fullname = REPLACE(REPLACE(filename, ' ', '_'),' ','.jpg')

I tried the following but the result was FirstName LastName_.jpg.

=Format(Parameters!Signature.Value, (Parameters!Signature.Value)&"")&".jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=Replace(Parameters!Signature.Value, " ", "_") & ".jpg"
```